# For $0<a<b$, why does $b^n-a^n=(b-a)(b^{n-1}+ab^{b-2}+...+a^{n-1})\implies b^n-a^n<(b-a)nb^{n-1}$?

Tags: inequality

For $0<a<b$, how does $b^n-a^n=(b-a)(b^{n-1}+ab^{b-2}+...+a^{n-1})\implies b^n-a^n<(b-a)nb^{n-1}$?

Clearly, $$\frac{b^n-a^n}{b-a}=b^{n-1}+ab^{n-2}+...+a^{n-1}$$ so I would need to see that $$b^{n-1}+ab^{n-2}+...+a^{n-1}<nb^{n-1}$$

Dividing through by $b^{n-1}$:$$1+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+...+\frac{a^{n-1}}{b^{n-1}}<n$$

Why should I believe this last inequality even?

Comment: Each of the fractions is strictly between $0$ and $1$

Comment: 0<a<b ; Replacing a by b: $(b^{n-1}+ab^{n-2}.......) <b^{n-1}+b^{n-1}.....) =nb^{n-1}$; ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 < a < b$ so $a^kb^{n-k-1} < b^{n-1}$.

So $b^{n-1} + ab^{n-2} + ...+ba^{n-2} + a^{n-1} < b^{n-1} + b^{n-1} + ...... + b^{n-1} + ^{n-1} = nb^{n-1}$.

......

$1+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+...+\frac{a^{n-1}}{b^{n-1}}<n$

"Why should I believe this last inequality even? "

Because $\frac {a^k}{b^k} < 1$ so

$1+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+...+\frac{a^{n-1}}{b^{n-1}} <1+1+1+......+1 = n$.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks a lot! Should've seen this myself :(